# hardy spaces: f is analytic in the closed disc implies the singular part of f is zero

Tags: complex-analysis, operator-theory, hardy-spaces

I am studying Banach Spaces of Analytic Function by Hoffman. After giving a description of nonzero $H^1$ functions as a factorization of Blaschke, Singular and Outer function, the author makes a remark that if $f$ is holomorphic in the closed unit disc then "singular part" of $f$ is zero and the Blaschke part of $f$ is a finite Blaschke product.

I wonder what the author means by the "singular part" of $f$ is zero because the factorization theorem would tell us that $f\equiv 0$.

I do not see how this remark follows. Here's my attempt, however to show that Blaschke product is finite: Let $f$ be analytic in the closed disc. Then $f$ must be analytic in a slightly bigger open connected set containing the closed unit disc. Now if there were infinitely many zeroes of $f$ in the open unit disc then they must accumulate somewhere in the closed unit disc (by Bolzano Weierstrass) and hence must be a zero function which would contradict our assumption. Thus the Blaschke part of $f$ is indeed a finite Blaschke product.

[image: The Factorization Theorem]

Comment: what it means is that the singular measure is zero so $S=1$ (which is obvious since any singular inner function that is not constant has indeed singularities on the unit circle pretty much by definition - on the support of the singular measure)

Comment: @Conrad I do not see why it's obvious. Can you please elaborate in an answer?

Comment: for every point $e^{i\theta}$ in the support of the singular measure $d\mu$ defining a singular inner function $S$  we know that $S(re^{i\theta}) \to 0, r \to 1$ - this is a standard theorem about the Poisson kernel; but $|S|=1$ almost everywhere on the unit circle by definition so $S$ cannot be even continuous at any unit circle point that is in its measure support, so it definitely cannot have analytic extension there

Comment: Thanks, that helped!